# How to send header in pagespeed tool of google

Tags: pagespeed

I need to test my website on page speed which consumes header for loading. How do I pass header in page speed for my website

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via Google Page Speed Insights.

However if you install the [Google Lighthouse CLI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) you can pass headers with the flag `--extra-headers`

(install with `npm install -g lighthouse` if you have node packet manager installed)